# Detect device rotation inside a collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

Inside a custom collectionVirewCell I create a gradient layer and add it to the cell in the function override `func awakeFromNib() {}`

```
 self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

When the device rotates the size of the cell changes but not the size of the layer. I need to do something like

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
```

}

The problem is that I get an error telling me that `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` did not override any function from the superclass. Is there any method to detect the cell size variation inside the cell class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is a `UIViewController` method and not a method of `UIView` which `UICollectionViewCell` inherits from.

The method you're looking to override is `layoutSubviews()`

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    <#code#>
}
```

I think that's your problem!